# Is there a way for copy a specific element of an ArrayList into another empty/different ArrayList?

Tags: java

-EDITED-
I'm studying for an exam on java, I have to create N object of Student after reading the information from the file.
And create the list of activities from keyboard.
For each Student I have to check all the activities and if I find an activity that has the same Student Surname, I have to copy in the Student object.

```
This are the class that I have created.
public class Student{
**String Surname;**
int Age;
ArrayList<Activity> list;
}

 public class Activity{
 **String Surname;**
 String ActName;
 int hour;
 }
```

Supposing to have read 2 students from files.

Student1 Rossi, 21
Student2 Holmes, 25

and assuming that i have entered 3 activities

Rossi Math 10hours
Holmes English 20Hours
Holmes Story 12Hours

My final output after copying the corresponding activities:

Student1 Rossi, 21, { Math 10hours}
Student2 Holmens, 25, { English 20Hours, Story 12Hours}

--- EDIT ---
I found a way for bypass the problem, I read the file checked if the Surname was the same of my object, if true I add the object to the list, if false continue to read the file. There was no reason to save in the list and after extract from it. Anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: You question is hard to follow. Try to rephrase it..

Comment: I'm not sure what exact problem you're facing. You can add, insert or replace elements in a list via the appropiate methods (`add(element)`, `add(index, element)` or `set(index, replacement)`). If you extract an element (actually the reference) from one list you can easily add it to another list, e.g. `targetList.add(sourcelist.get(some_index))` (I'll omit the necessary checks for simplicity). Just keep in mind that what will be "copied" is the reference to that element, i.e. if you change its contents you'll see that reflected in both lists. Is that what you want or are you after `clone()`?

Comment: I try to rephrase, I have a list of activity in this format (Surname, Activityname,Age) that I read from keyboard.
and N student's object read from a file following the format I wrote in the code part above (public class Student). if the activity Surname is the same I have to copy the element of the list in the Student object with the same Surname. It can be the same I don't have to change the list so I can clone/copy the list, but I need only the element with same username

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for copy a specific element of an ArrayList into another empty/different ArrayList?

1. You can find an element of a list by iterating the list, and testing each element; e.g.

   ```
   for (ElementType element: list) {
       if (/* some test on 'element' */) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. To test if two string values are equal, use the `equals` method; e.g.

   ```
   if (str1.equals(str2)) {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. To add an element to an list, use the `add` method; e.g.

   ```
   list.add(element);
   ```

This is not *copying* the object, but if you read the question, it is probably not *asking* you to copy the object into the list.